# Unity 2D - sprite flicker while follow object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im creating simple script which tells gameobject that it needs to follow other gameobject in defined distance.

code:

```
void Update()
{
    objPos = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position;
    transform.position = new Vector3(objPos.x + 0.5f, objPos.y + 0.5f);

}
```

problem is: following gameobject is flickering. When you watch it, it appears to be few frames behind followed gameobject. I noticed it before in my earlier prototype but now its crutial for my new game. So i think its pretty common issue.

Is there sollution for this unwanted behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Just for fun, does changing the method name to `LateUpdate()` do anything significant? Do you have VSync enabled when you play the game? You should definetly observe the behaviour when it's continously at 60FPS vs when it isn't locked. Are you sure the flickering doesn't have to do anything with the sprite order (i.e. order in the layer)? If they're on the same layer, this causes visible flickering since the z-Order of these objects change randomly. Performancewise, it would be wise to fix the `objPos` (e.g. make it public and assign it in the inspector), searching everytime for maybe costly.

Comment: Are you looking for a true "follow" (meaning velocity is in the equation), or for the object to statically always be .5x.5 away from the player object?

Comment: I tried LateUpdate before. Same outcome. Changing order in layer does not help. Storing gameobject separately does not help either.

Comment: I am looking for gameobjec statically be .5 x 5 away from player. (well not 0,5 literally but its only for testing purpose)

Comment: I would recommend making it a pre-fab or composite game object.  Then the engine handles the offset for you in relationship to the player object (i.e. make it a child of the player object).  Especially if it's just for testing as you can then just remove the object out of the pre-fab/composite or make it invisible.

Comment: okay this is sollution. But its problematic in my case because player object is rotating (so following object is rotating either). And my followed object should also rotate accord to third object (arrow pointing into direction of another third object). Its getting little complicated i know :)))

Comment: Well.. I believe you could make a prefab, have both the player object and the arrow object be children of that.  Then you should be able to rotate the player independent of the arrow, and still retain the offset position of the arrow.  You'd set sprite position via the prefab location, but rotation in the embedded player sprite. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: okay that makes sense. I just need to make some arrangements to suit it for my sollution. Definitely i will give a shot. Thanks mush

Answer (score 0):

GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player") has high performance cost, instead of using it each frame, hold an instance of the player. If the player is constant in the scene,

```
public Transform playerTransform;

void Update()
{
    transform.position = playerTransform.position + new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f);
}
```

and then assign the Player transform in Unity editor to this object using inspector. (Or dynamically in the code)

If your Player object gets destroyed and a new one instantiates once in a while, you can either assign the new one to the follower objects, or use a simple accessor method like this:

```
Transform _playerTransform;
Transform playerTransform
{
    get
    {
        if(_playerTransform == null)
        {
            _playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        }
        return _playerTransform;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    transform.position = playerTransform.position + new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly i tried it before and this is not the case :( thanks anyway